# Update Zsh prompt with sudo timeout information

Tags: sudo, zsh, prompt

I would like my Zsh prompt to display whether my `sudo` credentials are cached.
What I have so far should help in explaining what I want to achieve.

```sh
function sudo-warning {
    if sudo -nl &>/dev/null; then
        echo -n " %{${fg[red]}%}%{$reset_color%}"
    # optionally, show a locked lock if no sudo credentials active
    #else
    #    echo -n " %{${fg[blue]}%}%{$reset_color%}"
    fi  
}

# Update prompt every 10 seconds
TMOUT=10
TRAPALRM() {
    zle reset-prompt
}

PROMPT='%n$(sudo-warning) '
```

The problem is that `sudo -nl &>/dev/null` updates the timestamp of the last `sudo` call, so no timeout is ever reached.
So, is there a way to get retrieve information about whether `sudo` still has my credentials cached, *without* updating the timeout itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me to tell whether the timeout is reached:

```
sudo-expired() [[ $(
  trap "" XFSZ
  limit filesize 0
  LC_ALL=C sudo -n true 2>&1) = *"password is required" ]]
```

That is, set the filesize limit to 0 for the update of the timestamp file to fail, but as long as we don't let that limit kill `sudo`, we're still able to tell if a password was required or not.

Used like in yours (with a few simplifications):

```
sudo-warning()
  if sudo-expired; then
    echo '%F{blue}%f'
  else
    echo '%F{red}%f'
  fi

TMOUT=10
TRAPALRM() zle reset-prompt
set -o promptsubst
PS1='%n$(sudo-warning) '
```

Comment: This is a very nice and clever hack! The nice thing about limiting the file size is that no emails are sent out, even if `mail_badpass` is set. This works perfectly for me. However, this might also be considered a security issue. I’ll try to contact the developers about this.

Comment: @timothymctim, note that I've already contacted the sudo (and some distro) maintainers a few years back about the implications of changing the limits (and other process attributes like signal handler).